# intellij idea custom output directory

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse I am able to configure output folder for every directory in project. For example:

src/main/java -> app/target/classes 
src/main/resources -> app/target/classes 
src/main/custom_data -> app/custom_data

I cannot find out how to specify output directory for my 'custom_data' folder in IDEA. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate module which would have your custom_data directory as a source root or a resource root. Then you'll be able to specify the output directory for that module.